# Deploy custom dll to report server bin folder from installer

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, windows-installer

I have to deploy a custom dll which used by the ssrs reports. Now I need to deploy my custom assembly in the report server bin folder.

For this I need to create an MSI which would deploy the custom dll to the report server bin folder. I need to execute a custom script which would copy my dll to the report server bin location.

How to get the report server bin folder path dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [directory search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain the bin folder path.